# Добавление GoogleMaps на сайт

Tags: php, google-maps-api, mysqli

Здравствуйте! Такая проблема. Есть база данных с адресами. Мне нужно вывести все адреса на страничку и под каждым адресом вывести гугл-карту с расположением этого адреса. В JS я не сильна, говорю сразу. Но на просторах интернета наткнулась на код, который помогает добавить маркеры на карту, используя адреса из БД. Этот код у меня не работает почему-то. Прошу вашего совета, как сделать правильный вывод гугл-карты.

Вот то, что я нашла и отредактировала:

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "adress");
?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
            #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Sample code written by August Li
            var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                       new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                       new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
            var center = null;
            var map = null;
            var currentPopup;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                bounds.extend(pt);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pt,
                    icon: icon,
                    map: map
                });
                var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
            }           
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                    }
                });
                      center = bounds.getCenter();
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                        <?php>
                        $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM poi_example");

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                          $name = $row['name'];
                          $lat = $row['lat'];
                          $lon = $row['lon'];
                          $desc = $row['desc'];

                          echo("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b><br />$desc');\n");

                        }
                        ?>



     }
     </script>
     </head>
     <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
     <div id="map"></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: 1. Ошибки в логе сервера есть? Если есть, показывайте. 2. Ошибки в консоли браузера есть? Если есть показывайте.

Comment: Да в том то и проблема, что никаких ошибок и нет. Просто ничего не выводится. Походу у меня в скрипте php-код не работает. Я пытаюсь var_dumpом вывести содержимое запроса, а он никак не реагирует. Собственно и на комментирование строк кода тоже.

Comment: То есть на странице в html коде у вас нет кучи строк `addMarker(...`?

Comment: Нет) Просто пустая страница. Могу скрин сделать.

Comment: Тогда делайте проверки при работе с базой, чтобы сообщения об ошибках выводились прямо в браузер. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php - Пример #1. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php Пример #1. Тут `mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM poi_example");` у вас не правильный синтаксис. Первым параметром идет идентификатор соединения!!! Читайте по ссылке про процедурный стиль.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Не внимательная я. Все прекрасно работает)